# Jenkins Predefined environment variables

Tags: unix, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

It is interesting that we must have used Jenkins predefined build environment variables like `$WORKSPACE`, `$BUILD_NUMBER` etc in a lot of our Jenkins job.

I find it boggling to understand that, how does Jenkins set rules such that when we print `$WORKSPACE`, it prints the current workspace of various jobs. How does it map the variable `$WORKSPACE` to the corresponding Jenkins Job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins needs to know certain things about your build environment and jobs in order to do its job properly. For instance it needs to know the current build number, the location where your project should be checked out, who started the current build, etc. These things are typically exposed to you through the web interface.

Jenkins also exposes this information to your build scripts through environment variables that are injected into your scripts by Jenkins when your it is first launched. These environment variables can then be picked up by your script to do whatever is necessary with them.

In the example you gave (`$WORKSPACE`) Jenkins needs to know the absolute path to this location on your build slave because if it didn't, it wouldn't be able to check out your source and build it. Since it knows this information it exposes it to you as well to make writing your scripts easier.

There's a complete list of generally available environment variables provided by Jenkins available [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-belowJenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables).

Comment: Agreed, what I am trying to understand is how does jenkins knows that for $WORKSPACE, it should go to the slave machine and map a corresponding directory.

Comment: When you configure your job you specify which agents it's allowed to build on (if you don't specify, it's all of them). Jenkins will pick one from the list of eligible agents at random. Each agent has a work directory which is configured ahead of time (see the "Remote work directory" in your agent configuration). Jenkins will schedule the job on your agent, the agent will pick up the job, check out the workspace in the work directory, and build your software.